# Citing Lines in Algorithm

Tags: numbering, tex-core, algorithms

In case I have algorithm written in LaTex, how to cite lines from that algorithm? For example, Lines 3-10 in the algorithm explains...

Thanks.

Comment: What algorithm package are you using? Can you provide the community with a minimal example that replicates your current setup? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have a complete document that starts and ends with \documentclass. In between, I have algorithm that I want to cite some lines from it, like lines 3-10.

Comment: Please provide that (minimal) document so we can replicate your setup.